# Confuse between past tense and past progressive

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

So this is the question:

Instruction: **Complete the sentences. Use the past progressive in the *while*-clauses. Use the simple past in the *when* -clauses.**

> When my best friend (*call*) _______ last night, I (*wash*) _______
>   the dishes.

My answer:

> When my best friend called last night, I was washing the dishes.

But i'm not sure about that. The clause "my best friend ______ last night" can means during the call or make a call. Since the instruction said *when*-clauses must use the simple past, we still have "I (*wash*) _______  the dishes." Which is, it must be during the wash isn't it? And we have to use past progressive on the last sentence.

So, what is it? Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Does this diagram help?

[image]

Your friend called at a specific moment in time. At that moment, you were washing the dishes, which is an activity that takes place over a span of time.